# Configure DNS failover without domain name in dnsmadeeasy

Tags: dns, server, linode

I have only IP address for my site and no domain name. How can I set DNS failover without domain name in dnsmadeeasy?

I am using dnsmadeeasy for dns-failover.

http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Submit a ticket in https://support.dnsmadeeasy.com, There good person and they answer you quickly

Comment: Thank you Faisal.

But I have no account of dnsmadeeasy. So if any one done this before please let me know it is possible or not.